# Shouldn't user.destroy() function also destroy session on Parse-Server?

Tags: session, parse-platform, parse-server, back4app

I'm deploying a react native app on back4app using Parse-Server3.9.0. I have a cloud function to delete a user like this:

```
Parse.Cloud.define("deleteUser", async (request) => {
    if (!request.user) {
        throw 'no user logged in. Impossible to delete account';
    }
    else {
       return await request.user.destroy({useMasterKey:true});
    }
});
```

After calling it from the client, the currentuser becomes null and the user is correctly deleted from the '_User' table. However, the session remains in the '_Session' table! It looks like a bug to me, but I'm not confident enough with Parse to claim it. I might have missed something. Any idea?

Have a good day,

Julien

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's working as intended-- You asked Parse to delete the User, not the Session. They're two separate objects so they must be deleted separately.

You can use an `afterDelete` hook in cloud code to delete any Session or Installation objects associated with the User.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! It this case, i believe the doc of the SDK is confusing. Here is the explanation of destoy() for a user object: "Wrap the default destroy behavior with functionality that logs out the current user when it is destroyed". In Parse's logic, "the functionality that logs out the user", also removes active session form disk.
Is there a use case where it is useful to keep the session after deleting a user? Otherwise I could try to add this feature on Parse.

Comment: @JulienGraisse I can't really speak for the design decisions made by the makers of Parse, but if I had to guess, it behaves this way for continuity. In no other case does destroying an object result in associated objects also being destroyed, so it could introduce a lot of confusion to developers. I don't know of a great reason why someone would want to keep Session objects and not Users, but it could introduce a lot of confusion if destroying one object implicitly destroys another, so I imagine that's why it doesn't work that way.